# How do I insert and render code snippets on a Haml page for a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, insert, haml, code-snippets

I have html and javascript code snippets that I want to render on a haml page, how do I do it? I'm looking for something that is similar to the html syntax of <pre><code>. Much thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:erb` or `:javascript` keywords.

```
%div
  :erb
    <p>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function foo(){
        console.log('foo');
      }
      foo();
    </script>
```

Or

```
%div
  :erb
    <p>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
    </p>
  :javascript
    function foo(){
      console.log('foo');
    }
    foo();
```

Also, you can use raw HTML without indentation

```
%div
  <p> 
  <a href="#">Test</a> 
  </p>
```

Comment: that's helpful, what I wanted is something like <pre><code> some html and javascript code to display on a page </code></pre>. What I did was insert these tags after the :erb keyword, seems to work ok. Is there something better? thanks for the helpful answer!